# Exibindo as tags de uma página web com recuo proporcional à profundidade do elemento na estrutura de árvore do documento

Tags: python, python-3.x, parser

Problema: Desenvolva a classe MyHTMLParser como uma subclasse de HTMLParser que, quando alimentada com um arquivo HTML, mostra os nomes das tags de início e fim na ordem em que aparecem no documento, e com um recuo proporcional à profundidade do elemento na estrutura de árvore do documento. Ignore os elementos HTML que não exigem uma tag de fim, como p e br.

O arquivo HTML utilizado: https://easyupload.io/d45c52

A saída deve ser:

```
html start
    head start
        title start
        title end
    head end
    body start
        h1 start
        h1 end
        h2 start
        h2 end
        ul start
            li start
...
        a end
    body end
html end
```

O que eu fiz:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs): #mostra valor do atributo href, se houver
        print (tag, "start")

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print(tag, "end")

infile = open("w3c.html", "r")
content = infile.read()
infile.close()
myparser = MyHTMLParser()
myparser.feed(content)
```

A minha saída foi:

```
html start
head start
title start
title end
head end
body start
h1 start
h1 end
p start
br start
p end
h2 start
h2 end
...
a start
a end
body end
html end
```

Como corrigir o código de forma a conseguir o recuo na saída?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os métodos `handle_starttag()` e `handle_endtag()` precisam ser redefinidos. Cada um deverá mostrar o nome do elemento correspondente à *tag*, recuado de forma apropriada.

A indentação é um valor inteiro incrementado a cada *token* de *tag* de início e decrementado a cada *token* de *tag* de fim. (Ignorei os elementos p e br.) O valor da indentação deverá ser armazenado como uma variável de instância do objeto analisador e inicializado no construtor.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    'analisador de doc. HTML que mostra tags indentadas '

    def __init__(self):
        'inicializa o analisador e a indentação inicial'
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.indent = 0            # valor da indentação inicial

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        '''mostra tag de início com indentação proporcional à
           profundidade do elemento da tag no documento'''
        if tag not in {'br','p'}:
            print('{}{} start'.format(self.indent*' ', tag))
            self.indent += 4

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        '''mostra tag de fim com indentação proporcional à
           profundidade do elemento da tag no documento'''
        if tag not in {'br','p'}:
            self.indent -= 4
            print('{}{} end'.format(self.indent*' ', tag))
```